# css margin not responsed

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

html code

```
<div id="page">
   <div id="container2">
      <div id="container1">
         <div id="mainarea">
            <?php include mainarea_constractor.php";?>
         </div>
         <div id="sidebar">
         //content_of_sidebar_goes_here
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Css code:

```
#page{
    margin:auto;
    width:990px;
    padding:0 10px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    background: url(/template/img/main/containt_bg.png) center center repeat-y;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2 {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:990px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:995px;
    position:relative;
    right:340px;
    border-right:1px double #c1c0a8;
    text-align:justify;
}
#mainarea {
    float:left;
    width:650px;
    left:340px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:5px;
}
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:330px;
    position:relative;
    left:345px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The problem is when i put a div into mainarea, i can't set margin or padding options
for example:

```
<div id="mainarea">
   <div style="margin-left:15px;" id="inner_div">
      Content_for_inner_div
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help?
When i set float into #inner_div works, but i don't want float into my divs...
I don't want to change my general template if possible (page,container2,container1)

Comment: I don't see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/GahtA/

Comment: @ptriek so the problem is here http://jsfiddle.net/GahtA/1/ .lesson_more content - hint:click on title

Comment: @user726730 At the risk of being labeled a comedian, that's all Greek to me. Where exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: i want margin-left into lesson_more class ---

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly i think the only way to use margins on a div that is inside like you want to is to use

```
float:left;
margin-left:15px;
```

It shouldnt break your style if you float left as long as the inner div is no bigger than the outer div that is holding it.

Check this link out http://jsfiddle.net/vabfs/